# Displaying HTML on client side after dynamically building it server side in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

I am dynamically building html on the code behind (while reading data from the database and creating button controls)

So my code behind is something like:

```
strHTML = <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='3'><tr><td align='center' valign='middle' width="150" height="50" class="bItem"><asp:Button CssClass='btnDashboard' width='170' Height='70' ID='Button2' runat='server' Text="MyProfile" /></td></tr></table>"
```

The above string is supposed to display dynamically created buttons on clientside.

My clientside code is:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><% %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I display the dynamically created HTML within the server tags?
I tried using div tags, but the buttons came out with no text, and I could not "click" them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add html controls,tags etc by this way

create a div in your page:

```
<div id="divtest" runat="server"></div>
```

Since runat="server" is there you can access the div in your code behind.Add your html code in this way.

```
 strHTML = "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='3'><tr><td align='center' valign='middle' width=""150"" height=""50"" class=""bItem""><asp:Button CssClass='btnDashboard' width='170' Height='70' ID='Button2' runat='server' Text=""MyProfile"" /></td></tr></table>"

 divtest.InnerHtml = strHTML
```

But you cant add asp controls like that.

```
 Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = name;
        b.ID = id;
        b.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);

form1.Controls.Add(GetButton("Button1", "Click"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add web server controls that way; you need to add them to the Page's control tree dynamically, if the controls are created dynamically.  MSDN explains this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178511.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [PlaceHolder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx) as the container for your dynamically generated buttons.

From your example, I am not sure if you are also generating a table as well, but if so, you could create it using the [HtmlTable Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.aspx) to generate the table containing your buttons.  The table can then be added to the placeholder.

The sample code on the PlaceHolder Class page shows how to add controls to a placeholder control, buttons coincidentally.